# Javascript -- Why am I able to show a hidden div, but not hide it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write a simple function to dynamically show or hide an element. I've written functions like this several times before and have never had an issue...I can't figure out what's going wrong here. I use Javascript to dynamically create the element, and then in the process of creating it and appending it to the page, I also write `$(element).css("display", "none")` so that it will be hidden on page load.

Now I'm writing an event listener function to display the hidden elements in response to a click event. When I click on the button with this event listener attached to it, the hidden elements DO appear (great!), but then when I click on the box again, they stay on the page. When I `console.log` out the function, I can see that it's always hitting the `show` condition and never hitting the `hide` condition...but I cannot figure out why after spending hours and hours looking at examples and trying different implementations.

To be clear, I did not assign `display: none;` in the static CSS stylesheet. I added it dynamically in the JS when I created the elements.

```
// Pass in an array of cards called "filterCards"

const toggleDisplayFilterCards = (filterCards) => {

// Loop through the cards, and for each card, grab the ID tag 
  for (let card of filterCards) {
    card = `#filter-card-container_${card.id}`;
    
   // If "display" style attribute = "none", show the div, else, hide it.
    if ($(card).css("display", "none")) {
      $(card).css("display", "")
      console.log("show");
    } else if ($(card).css("display", "")) {
      $(card).css("display", "none");
      console.log("hide");
    }
  }
};
```

Does anyone see a reason why this code would never hit the "hide" condition? I've inspected the element in the console once it's displayed on the page, and confirmed that the style attribute *has* been changed to `""`, so when I click the same button, I would expect the function to hit the "hide" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What these two do

```
$(card).css("display", "none")
$(card).css("display", "")
```

is they set the style of the card, and then return the jQuery object containing the card. Objects are always truthy in JavaScript, so doing

```
if ($(card).css("display", "none")) {
```

doesn't make sense.

You need to *retrieve* the style (done with a single parameter), then compare it against the possible value.

```
if ($(card).css("display") === "none") {
...
} else {
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much for your time. It won't let me accept this as the answer for another minute, but as soon as I can, I will. Thanks again.

Comment: @MickeyVershbow *Consider* also using [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) or [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)